# Filter array of associative rows by flat associative array with one or more elements

Tags: php, arrays, function, filtering, associative-array

I'm working with an inventory database (yes, I know that this could potentially be done using mysql), but I currently end up with a PHP array.

```
$products = [
    ["id" => "123", "sku" => "MED_BL_DRESS", "size" => "medium", "color" => "black"],
    ["id" => "321", "sku" => "LG_GR_DRESS", "size" => "large", "color" => "green"],
    ["id" => "31321", "sku" => "LG_RD_DRESS", "size" => "large", "color" => "red"]
]
```

The user will select a size, and I want to pass into the function:

```
 filterArray($products, ["size"=>"medium"])
```

and I'm hoping that I can get an array back, with only records which matched that criteria... the kicker is if I pass multiple criteria,

```
 filterArray($products, ["size"=>"medium", "color"=>"black"])
```

then the array would give me back a products array with just that one product matching in the array. I'm trying to build this so that I can have any number of key values in the products array (perhaps some products have "gender" as a filter, whereas others won't). It could have many, many filter variants.

I tried looping over the array and brute forcing it, but I think there must be a more elegant way then a bunch of nested recursive functions.

Comment: So `basically` you want to filter the array based on any `value`? As well, you need to insert what have you tried so far

Comment: Check these links: 1. [php foreach with multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413589/php-foreach-with-multidimensional-array) 2. [PHP: Foreach in a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322612/php-foreach-in-a-multidimensional-array) 3. [How to foreach multidimensional array with key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38720862/how-to-foreach-multidimensional-array-with-key-value)

Comment: @Nathan do you have a preferred answer on this page?

Answer (score 0):

Why do think it is so hard?
No recursion needed.

This answer assumes you want all results to match by AND logic. You also could extend the filter function to make use of a second array for OR logic. In ElasticSearch there is a terminology of MUST and SHOULD.

- The first will find all sizes 'large'
  (two results)
- The second will find all sizes 'large' and color 'green'
  (one result)

### Filter Explanation

- A key counter is used to know how many keys of the product must match
- The outer loop will go through all products
- For each iteration the match counter is reset to 0
- Then compare how many matches are in the filter against the current product
- When the matches equal the keycount, then all filters passed positive and add the product to the results.

```
$products = [
    ["id" => "123", "sku" => "MED_BL_DRESS", "size" => "medium", "color" => "black"],
    ["id" => "321", "sku" => "LG_GR_DRESS", "size" => "large", "color" => "green"],
    ["id" => "31321", "sku" => "LG_RD_DRESS", "size" => "large", "color" => "red"]
];

print_r(filterArray($products, ['size' => 'large']));
print_r(filterArray($products, ['size' => 'large', 'color' => 'green']));

function filterArray(array $products, array $filter = []): array
{
    $result = [];
    $keyCount = count($filter);
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $match = 0;
        foreach ($filter as $key => $value)
            if ($product[$key] === $value) $match++;
        if ($match === $keyCount) $result[] = $product;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for that. Additionally, you could pass an extra param to indicate if the row must match *all* the filters or if it can match *any* filter to make the function more dynamic and useful:

[Working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b1c8bae6bdb3976eda2125e09f0abdb27360b6f4)

```
/**
 * @param array $products
 * @param array $filters
 * @param bool $matchAll
 * @return array
 */
function filterArray(array $products, array $filters, bool $matchAll = true): array
{
    return array_filter($products, static function($product) use ($filters, $matchAll) {
        $matches     = 0;
        $filterCount = count($filters);
        foreach ($filters as $filterColumn => $filterValue) {

            if (isset($product[$filterColumn]) && $product[$filterColumn] === $filterValue) {
                $matches++;
                if (!$matchAll) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return  ($matches && !$matchAll) || ($matchAll && ($matches === $filterCount));
    });
}


$products = [
    ["id"=>"123", "sku"=>"MED_BL_DRESS", "size"=>"medium", "color"=>"black"],
    ["id"=>"321", "sku"=>"LG_GR_DRESS", "size"=>"large", "color"=>"green"],
    ["id"=>"31321", "sku"=>"LG_RD_DRESS", "size"=>"large", "color"=>"red"]
];



// Filter matching all filters
$filters = ["size"=>"medium", "color"=>"black"];
$filteredProducts = filterArray($products, $filters);
var_dump($filteredProducts);



// Filter matching any of the filters
$filters = ["size"=>"medium", "color"=>"black",  "sku"=>"LG_RD_DRESS"];
$filteredProducts = filterArray($products, $filters, false);
var_dump($filteredProducts);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses the [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-filter.php)() function. In the callback function, [array_intersect_assoc](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-intersect-assoc.php)() is used to check whether all elements of the $ filter array are present in the line.

```
function filterArray(array $products, array $filter = []): array
{
  return array_filter(
    $products, 
    function($row) use($filter){
      return array_intersect_assoc($filter, $row) === $filter;
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter how many qualifying associative elements you have, check the `$mustHave` whitelist array against each row of the `$product` array with `!array_diff_assoc()` for maximum functional-style elegance.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7uBf8))

```
$products = [
    ["id" => "123", "sku" => "MED_BL_DRESS", "size" => "medium", "color" => "black"],
    ["id" => "321", "sku" => "LG_GR_DRESS", "size" => "large", "color" => "green"],
    ["id" => "31321", "sku" => "LG_RD_DRESS", "size" => "large", "color" => "red"]
];

$mustHave = ['size' => 'large', 'color' => 'green'];

var_export(
    array_filter(
        $products,
        fn($row) => !array_diff_assoc($mustHave, $row)
    )
);
```