# How to get values from checkboxes to php array on button click?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a problem. I want to get checked values from checkboxes and add them to a php array but i have no clue on how to do it. I can do it in javascript but i want a php array and i don't know how to convert js array to php array. I am gonna use the array in next php file and search rows from database with those values. I would appreciate if anybody suggests something on how to do it as i have no clue.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search)) {
            $category = $row["Category"];
            echo<inputtype=\"checkbox\"name=\"category\"value=\"$category\"required/>$kategoria</input><br /><br />";
}

<a id='answer' href='questions.php'><button>Answer to questions!</button></a>
```

This is how i make the checkboxes and then on button click i move to the next file

Comment: PHP and JavaScript on the web page have separate non-overlapping life spans. It get a JS array to PHP you need to do an ajax call back to the server

Comment: first of all your code have some mistakes. i hope those were from copy/paste. you just have to put your checkboxes into a html form then post your form to php file. then in php u have have to get values from those checkboxes like $_POST['category']. if they are not checked then they wont be posted so you have check $_POST array if they exist first.

Comment: Are you looking to do a regular submission or an AJAX request?

Answer (score 0):

add attribute action=questions.php, method="post" to form instead of using < a href="questions.php"> and place  in form and use extract($$__REQUEST) at very first line of questions.php use print_r(extract($_REQUEST)) to print extracted data from form to associative array.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your form:

```
<form method="POST" action="questions.php">
    <input type="checkbox" name="myInput" id="myInput" value="checked" />
    <label for="myInput">Checkbox</label>

    <!-- A submit button -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit values" />
</form>
```

Then in questions.php, all your values are added to the variable $_POST:

```
// Foreach item in the POST array.
foreach ($_POST as $item => $value) {

    // The value will be stored in $value
}
```

If the checkbox is checked, the $value variable will be **checked**. Otherwise it will be empty.

Source: [PHP: Foreach in a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322612/php-foreach-in-a-multidimensional-array)